# Is it possible to connect from USB-B to eSATA?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, esata

I have a SATA drive docking station which came with a USB-B to USB-A cable. If I purchased a USB-B to eSATA cable would it still transfer at the USB 2.0 rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any connection like this will always run at the speed of the slowest step in this case the USB 2.0 connection.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer may be maybe, but unlikely.

Most budget docking stations have the same insides and are native/good SATA, with cheap/low end USB converters.

If you get near native speeds on Esata, but, very low speeds on USB (I am talking much lower than the 480Mbps), it is possible that getting a high end/good Esata to USB Converter could make the speeds slightly faster... but, you will never be able to get faster than the maximum USB 2 Speed.